# Wait for loop to finish, facebook API?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, backbone.js

Is there a way to improve the way I am pushing the objects?

My problem is `console.log(facebookPlayers)` is empty, but with a setTimeout it shows the new object array. Obviously because it's being called before the object array populates.

I plan on building a backbone collection with this object array, this was my initial idea for building an object array from the facebook API. Perhaps there is a better way, or perhaps this works, but if it does I need to figure out a way to wait until the object is fully populated.

```
var facebookPlayers = [];

FB.api('/554870764588961/members/', function (response) {
    for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
        FB.api(response.data[i].id+'/picture', function (response) {
            facebookPlayers.push({key:response.data.url});
        });
    }
});

console.log(facebookPlayers)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea to call the API again for every single member. It is very slow and you may reach an API limit. You should consider using [nested queries](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#fieldexpansion):

```
function getPlayers(callback) {
    var facebookPlayers = [];

    FB.api('/554870764588961?fields=members{id,name,picture}', function (response) {
        for (var i = 0, count = response.data.length; i < count; i++) { 
            facebookPlayers.push({key:response.data[i].picture.data.url});
        }
        callback(facebookPlayers);
    });
}

getPlayers(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Not tested, but the API call works in the [API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) so it should be no problem.

Edit: I´ve also fixed the scope for "i" and made the loop a bit faster.

Comment: I was hoping to hear this. I had a bad feeling about that and this confirms it. Thanks

Comment: well, it was a quick test, you should read the facebook docs about nested queries. also, make sure to think about pagination if there are more members. see "Traversing Paged Results" in the docs.

Comment: I feel like this works, but I ran into `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` is that loop correct?

Comment: Okay I see, I will read up on it and see if I can fix that. Could be because I am using v2.0 let me try to update to v2.2

Comment: well, i only tested the api call in the api explorer. since length is only used in the for loop, try console.log(response) first.

Comment: ah, yeah - the version could be the problem. i believe they did something with field expansion in v2.1.

Comment: Good call though, it gave me an error `code: 100message: "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"type: "GraphMethodException"` I think I didnt update properly, but I get the picture, I think your work here is done let me play with the graph explorer and make sure I am updating properly.

Comment: since you are using the JS SDK, all you need to do is change the version string in FB.init.

Comment: Yeah thats what I did, I wasnt sure if there was another thing I had to do. Somehow you changed the group ID, I changed it to the right group ID lol and it worked. Thanks about to green check once I confirm its working :)

Comment: oh, i am sorry. that was my own group :)

Comment: Yeah I assumed that was probably it, not sure why it wouldn't work though maybe permissions. But yeah it works now thanks for helping me optimize this, it's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Last thing though, is this what you would call a promise?

Comment: no, i would not use a promise for this. they are nice, but not necessery for just one callback. that´s a promise: https://www.promisejs.org/

Comment: so you would also need to include a promise library, or a fallback for the native promise that comes with ES6.

Comment: Oh this is just a simple callback lol I miss read the other posters comment, he said callback or promise haha. Okay thanks though have a good one!

Comment: Yeah thats what I always thought, and never really had a need for using them.

Answer (score 0):

The console.log() runs before the call comes back ... putting it inside the callback will allow you to see what is being added. As below ...

```
var facebookPlayers = [];

FB.api('/554870764588961/members/', function (response) {
    for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
        FB.api(response.data[i].id+'/picture', function (response) {
            facebookPlayers.push({key:response.data.url});
            console.log(facebookPlayers)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah but I am trying to do something like this `var testCollection = new PlayersCollection(facebookPlayers);
                    window.App.data.facebookPlayers = testCollection;` outside of the loop.

Comment: I dont want to loop the console log response I want to see the complete array response so I can pass that into the collection. Should have specified that.

Comment: But how am I supposed to create a new instance of a backbone collection inside a for loop. Ill end up with 53 instances. 53 for the amount of response objects.

Comment: Add the facebookPlayers array to the signature of your callback i.e functuion (response, facebookPlayers)? It will then be in scope and you should be able to see populated instance outside of the callback

Answer (score 0):

The facebook methods are asynchronous. Make use of a callback or promises. *Never* use a timeout to assume when something is ready.

Callback example:

```
function doFacebookStuff(complete){
    var facebookPlayers = [];
    FB.api('/554870764588961/members/', function (response) {
        for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
            FB.api(response.data[i].id+'/picture', function (response) {
                facebookPlayers.push({key:response.data.url});
                if(i === response.data.length-1)
                    complete(facebookPlayers); 
                    // callback when all calls are done
            });
        }
    });
}

doFacebookStuff(function(facebookPlayers){
    console.log(facebookPlayers);
});
```

Comment: I agree on the Timeout lol thats obvious, I just did it to get the response, thanks this looks good.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry My pleasure. Let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: Unfortunately its not working :( did you test this or just write it from scratch. I dont know anything about promises, I should but I dont.

Comment: Yeah I will, it might be hard getting the facebook api to work. Il build a random collection. But since this is async IDK.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Hang on, let me setup a dummy example